# Need to drop every instance of "score" after first occurrence on each line

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xpath

```
<RepairOrderEvent>
      <EventType>Advisor - Shared Guidelines</EventType>
      <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
      <EventNotes>FAF: Refinish Time without Haz Waste or EPC Charge; Score: 11; Variance: 0.0; UniqueSequenceNum: 0; Insurance Score: 40</EventNotes>
    </RepairOrderEvent>
    <RepairOrderEvent>
      <EventType>Advisor - Shared Guidelines</EventType>
      <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
      <EventNotes>FAF(Best Practice): Must Enter If Vehicle is Drivable; Score: 11; Variance: 0.0; UniqueSequenceNum: 0</EventNotes>
    </RepairOrderEvent>
    <RepairOrderEvent>
      <EventType>Advisor - Shared Guidelines</EventType>
      <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
      <EventNotes>FAF(Best Practice): Bumper Overlap Prompt Answered Yes, No Estimate Line Note; Score: 11; Variance: 0.0; UniqueSequenceNum: 2; Insurance Score: 25</EventNotes>
    </RepairOrderEvent>
    <RepairOrderEvent>
      <EventType>Advisor - Shared Guidelines</EventType>
      <EventDateTime>2019-01-07T11:18:38.8756279-06:00</EventDateTime>
      <EventNotes>FAF(Document): Insufficient Photos Provided: Include Damage Area; Score: 11; Variance: 0.0; UniqueSequenceNum: 0; Insurance Score: 10000</EventNotes>
    </RepairOrderEvent>
```

I have the following XML Data. I am trying to find the aggregate of "score" and not "score" + "Insurance Score". I was thinking of using Xpath to find the first occurrence of score on each line and drop the remainder of the string. The end goal here is to be able to read each line for the first occurrence, drop the remainder of the string and find the sum of the score.

Any suggestions or help is welcomed and appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: If you try to do this via simply string manipulation, you are in for a world of hurt.  Walk through the file using an XML technology (the DOM, Linq4Xml or something) and remove the attribute.

Comment: Could you solve this issue using Regex? Or is there some restriction to only using xpath? Regex would allow you to pull all matches that are in the format: `Score: ##;` and you could sum them that way.

Comment: If the order of the string elements is static, you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression to get the `Score` values: `substring-before(substring-after(text(),'Score: '),';')`. The task that remains is adding the results.

Comment: @dvo No restriction, it was just an initial thought and I'll make sure to give that a try now that you mention it.

Comment: @JVasquez0823 this Regex pattern may help: `(?<=; Score: )[^;]+` It is a positive look behind. It matches anything that is "; Score: <anything to semicolon>" but only returns the number you are looking for. You can use that to look through the Regex Matches and parse the number and add it to a running total. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're at the point where you're processing the values of the `EventNotes` you could do something like this assuming every `EventNotes` has some kind of "Score".

```
  var num = eventNotes
    .Select(note => note
      .Split(";")
      .Where(part => part.Contains("Score"))
      .Select(score => int.Parse(score.Split(' ')[1]))
      .First())
    .Aggregate((sum, val) => sum + val);
```

Which would give you the sum of all the first occurrences of a score in all EventNotes.
This is assuming you already have the XML parsing part though.